# How to use onCharacteristicWrite() for BLE in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm implementing a small BLE app and I have a list of devices and I want to turn them off when I press on them in the list view.

My service UUID is:0xFFB0

My characteristic UUID is:0xFFB7 Write with response/ Read with response

Characteristic format:

Byte order ; 0 ; 1~19

R/W    ON/OFF ; -

0x01 -> ON and 0x00 -> OFF

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var macList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
private var deviceList: ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> = ArrayList()
private lateinit var adapter: ArrayAdapter<String>
private var mBtAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = null
private var mConnectedGatt: BluetoothGatt? = null
private var mCharacteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic? = null
private var on = true
private lateinit var currentDevice: BluetoothDevice

/**
 * CHECK IF BT AND LOCATION IS ON!
 */
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    if (!isBLESupported(this)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "This device doesn't support bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        finish()
    } else {
        if (!mBtAdapter!!.isEnabled) {
            val enableBluetoothIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
            startActivityForResult(enableBluetoothIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH)
        }
    }

    adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, macList)
    list_view.adapter = adapter

    list_view.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
        currentDevice = deviceList[position]
        mConnectedGatt = currentDevice.connectGatt(applicationContext, false, gattCallback)
    }

    scan_button.setOnClickListener {
        scanForDeviceWithFilter(LIGHT_SERVICE)
    }

    power_button.setOnClickListener {
        mConnectedGatt = currentDevice.connectGatt(applicationContext, true, powerCallback)
        on = !on
    }

}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    //Disconnect from any active tag connection
    if (mConnectedGatt != null) {
        mConnectedGatt!!.disconnect()
        mConnectedGatt = null
    }
}

private fun scanForDeviceWithFilter(serviceUUID: Int) {

    val uuid = ParcelUuid(convertFromInteger(serviceUUID))
    val filter = ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(uuid).build()
    val filters = listOf(filter)
    val settings = ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY).build()
    checkBTPermissions()
    mBtAdapter!!.bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(filters, settings, scanDevicesCallback)
    Thread.sleep(3000)
    mBtAdapter!!.bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(scanDevicesCallback)

}

private val scanDevicesCallback = object : ScanCallback() {
    override fun onBatchScanResults(results: MutableList<ScanResult>?) {
        results?.forEach { result ->
            macList.add(result.device.toString())
            Log.d(TAG, "device name:${result.device}")
        }
    }

    override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult?) {
        result?.let {
            if (!macList.contains(result.device.name.toString())) {
                deviceList.add(result.device)
                macList.add(result.device.name.toString())
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "device found:${result.device}")
        }

    }

    override fun onScanFailed(errorCode: Int) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Scan failed $errorCode")
    }
}


private val gattCallback = object : BluetoothGattCallback() {

    /* OK */
    override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt, status: Int, newState: Int) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection State Change: " + status + " -> " + connectionState(newState))
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS && newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            /**
             * Once successfully connected, we must next discover all the services on the
             * device before we can read and write their characteristics.
             */
            gatt.discoverServices()
            Thread.sleep(500)
        } else if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            /**
             * If there is a failure at any stage, simply disconnect
             */
            gatt.disconnect()
        }
    }

    private fun connectionState(status: Int): String {
        return when (status) {
            BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED -> "Connected"
            BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED -> "Disconnected"
            BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTING -> "Connecting"
            BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTING -> "Disconnecting"
            else -> status.toString()
        }
    }

    override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int) {

        mCharacteristic = gatt?.getService(convertFromInteger(LIGHT_SERVICE))?.getCharacteristic(convertFromInteger(PASSWORD_CHARACTERISTIC))
        mCharacteristic!!.setValue("0123")
        if (gatt!!.writeCharacteristic(mCharacteristic)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login success")
            Thread.sleep(500)
        } else
            Log.d(TAG, "Login failed")
    }

    override fun onCharacteristicWrite(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic?, status: Int) {
        if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            Log.d("onCharacteristicWrite", "Failed write, retrying: $status")
            gatt!!.writeCharacteristic(characteristic)
        }
        super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status)
    }
}


private val powerCallback = object : BluetoothGattCallback() {

    /* OK */
    override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt, status: Int, newState: Int) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection State Change: " + status + " -> " + connectionState(newState))
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS && newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            gatt.discoverServices()
            Thread.sleep(500)
        } else if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            gatt.disconnect()
        }
    }

    private fun connectionState(status: Int): String {
        return when (status) {
            BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED -> "Connected"
            BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED -> "Disconnected"
            BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTING -> "Connecting"
            BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTING -> "Disconnecting"
            else -> status.toString()
        }
    }

    override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int) {

        if (on) {
            mCharacteristic = gatt!!.getService(convertFromInteger(LIGHT_SERVICE))?.getCharacteristic(convertFromInteger(LIGHT_CHARACTERISTIC))
            mCharacteristic!!.setValue("0")

            gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(mCharacteristic, true)
            if (gatt.writeCharacteristic(mCharacteristic)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Power off success")
                Thread.sleep(500)
            } else Log.d(TAG, "Power off failed")
        } else {
            mCharacteristic = gatt!!.getService(convertFromInteger(LIGHT_SERVICE))?.getCharacteristic(convertFromInteger(LIGHT_CHARACTERISTIC))
            mCharacteristic!!.setValue("1")
            if (gatt.writeCharacteristic(mCharacteristic)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Power on success")
                Thread.sleep(500)
            } else Log.d(TAG, "Power on failed")
        }

    }


    override fun onCharacteristicWrite(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic?, status: Int) {
        if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            Log.d("onCharacteristicWrite", "Failed write, retrying: $status")
            gatt!!.writeCharacteristic(characteristic)
        }
        super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
    }

}

private fun isBLESupported(context: Context): Boolean {
    return BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter() != null && context.packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)
}


init {
    mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
}

private fun checkBTPermissions() {
    val permissionCheck = checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION")
    if (permissionCheck != 0) {
        requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), 1001)
    }
}

fun convertFromInteger(i: Int): UUID? {
    val msb = 0x0000000000001000L
    val lsb = -0x7fffff7fa064cb05L
    val value = (i and ((-0x1).toLong()).toInt()).toLong()
    return UUID(msb or (value shl 32), lsb)
}

companion object {
    private const val TAG = "Main Activity"
    private const val LIGHT_SERVICE = 0xffb0
    private const val LIGHT_CHARACTERISTIC = 0xffb7
    private const val PASSWORD_CHARACTERISTIC = 0xffba
    private const val REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 1
}
}
```

I changed my code, but now when I try to write I get status = 128;  GATT_NO_RESOURCES and I have no clue what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have understand the flow correctly.

The `onCharacteristicWrite` is *not* called "to send data to the BLE device". It is being called *after* you have called `writeCharacteristic`, after the remote device has responded.

> This callback is called when you are trying to send data using writeCharacteristic(characteristics) and the BLE device responds with some value.

This is not really correct about `onCharacteristicChanged`. This method is called whenever the local device receives a *notification* from the remote device. To enable this you must first tell the local Bluetooth stack to forward the notifications to you by calling `setCharacteristicNotification` first, and write the *client characteristic configuration descriptor* to the remote device so it will send notifications.

After you have called `writeDescriptor`, the `onDescriptorWrite` callback will be called when the remote device responds.

What you should do is to implement the `onServicesDiscovered` method which will be called as a result of `discoverServices`, when the service discovery is complete. In this callback you can call `writeCharacteristic` on the ON/OFF characteristic.

From your description it doesn't seem you need to receive notifications.

Comment: Thank you for you help @Emil. I changed my code but now I get status 128 = NO_GATT_RESOURCES. U have any ideea how can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have too many BLE connections? And in which callback do you get this status code?

Comment: I have 2 GATT connections, first I must write a characteristic to login to the device, and after that, I try to write a characteristic to turn it on/off. I tried to disconnect 1 of them and then connect to the second one, but I still get 128. I updated my question with the full code. I'm lost honestly and I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I was sending a string to the device, not a byte value.

mCharacteristic!!.value = byteArrayOf(0x00) fixed my problem.